# Entity Framework child objects not populating

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a simple model which when I run the website in the debugger the entity framework does not correctly populate the model.

The model is simple:

```
public class Team
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor required for the EntityFramework to create the object.
    /// </summary>
    private Team()
    {            
    }

    public Team(string name, ApplicationUser owner)
    {
        Name = name;
        Owner = owner;
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public List<TeamMembership> Members { get; set; }
}


public class TeamMembership
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Constructor for the EntityFramework
    /// </summary>
    private TeamMembership()
    {
    }

    public TeamMembership(ApplicationUser user, MembershipStatus status)
    {
        User = user;
        Status = status;
    }

    [Required]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; private set; }

    [Required]
    public MembershipStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Where `ApplicationUser` is the default class generated by the ASP MVC 5 membership infrastructure.

When I run my tests (Specflow), which create a new LocalDb database with a unique id for each test and runs the migrations on that db,  then the entity framework correctly populates my Team and the Owner.

However when I run the website and try and interact with the application then my Team is not fully populated, because the Owner is `null` and `Members` is not populated.  But the owner ID is set correctly in the database and the query seems ok.  The queries executed during the test and the running of the app seem the same.

Why might this be and how might I start to debug the issue?

I feel like I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably need to add `.Include()` to your query, which isn't shown in your question, but should look something like this:

```
var query = context.Teams.Include(x => x.Owner).Include(x => x.Members).Where( ... );
```

EF will only load the top-level entities, but not the entities referenced by it until they're needed (lazy loading). If you haven't disposed of the context, simply attempting to access those navigation properties should cause them to load from the database, but this won't happen if the context has been disposed of.

`.Include()` will inform EF that those navigation properties need to be eagerly loaded along with the referencing entity.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for more detail about lazy/eager loading and how to control it.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  This does indeed seem to have solved the problem.  However I'm a bit confused as to why my integration tests (which call methods on the controller) worked and had full populated objects.  Is it due to the context lifetime?  I think my tests create a context for the lifetime of the test, which may be several controller method invocations, and when running in IIS SimpleInjector will create a DBContext per call.  But the dbcontext should not have been disposed between loading the team and navigating the owner/members

Comment: If the context hasn't been disposed of (and the entity is still attached to the context), and you access a navigation property, EF should hit the database again to grab that entity. If the context is disposed, this cannot happen. I'll add a link to the answer for more information.

Comment: Will an entity still be attached to the context unless it has explicitly been detached?

Comment: In C# 6 you can now use `nameof` for a little more type safety. For example, `.Include(nameof(Team.Owner))`.

Comment: Or if you are using an earlier EntityFramwork version, such as v 4.   
`var query = context.Teams.Include("Owner").Include("Members").Where( ... );`